# iOS 9 and most recent contacts on top of screen in app switcher

Tags: contacts, ios

There used to be icons at the top showing who you recently texted or called when you double clicked the home button. But with iOS 9 update, it's no longer there.  Is it gone forever or is now a setting that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 5):

That feature is no longer located in the App Switcher, but instead (on iPhone 5 and later) can be found when one swipes to the very left page of the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..it HAS gone!   Swiping from left to right produces a changing display of Siri 'suggestions' based on a fluctuating range of what has been most recently accessed.  It does not keep your favourite numbers constant and accessible as before at the top of the screen.  A bitter blow!!

Answer (score -1):

That feature hasn't moved, it's gone.  The new way requires getting to the home screen, swiping, tapping, then tapping again to call. Four steps whereas before it as double-click home button from anywhere, tap and go.

This is a de-enhancement and not a new feature.  The OP got a how-to, but Asking Different would be "Why was a great feature made so bad."